# How to find CDF of $Y=|X|\wedge 2$ with $X\sim Laplace(\lambda)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, linear-transformations, density-function, monotone-functions

Given $X$ a bilateral exponential with density $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda=1$, i have to find CDF of $Y=|X|\wedge 2$.

I know that $Y$ is not a monotonic function, so i can't apply the law of transformation of random variables. 
I know that the support of $Y$ is $[0,2]$, so i can write $F_Y(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & if & y<0\\ 
? & if & 0\leq y\leq 2\\ 
1 & if &y>2 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Then:

$F_y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(|X|\wedge 2\leq y)=...$

How can I continue?

Comment: Remember $\lvert X\rvert\wedge 2=\min(\lvert X\rvert,2)$, so this is $\leq y$ when $\lvert X\rvert\leq y$ (since $y\leq 2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this for $0\leq y\leq 2$ so $|X|\wedge2\leq y$ is the same statement as $|X|\leq y$.

That means that you can continue with:$$\cdots=P(|X|\leq y)=\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, again! So: $P(|X|\wedge 2\leq y)=P(|X|\leq y)=P(-y\leq |X|\leq y)=\int_{-y}^{y}f_X(x)dx=\int_{-y}^{0}f_X(x)dx+\int_{0}^{y}f_X(x)dx=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-y})+(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}-\frac{1}{2})=-e^{-y}$.         But solution says that $F_Y(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & if & y\leq 0\\ 
1-e^{-y} & if & 0<y\leq 2\\ 
1 & if & y>2
\end{matrix}\right.$ Where I wrong?

Comment: I've bisected $|x|=\left\{\begin{matrix}x & for & x\geq0\\ -x & for & x< 0\end{matrix}\right.$. So I obtain $\int_{-y}^{0}\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}dx=\int_{-y}^{0}\frac{1}{2}e^{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}[e^x]_{-y}^0=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}$ and $\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}dx=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{2}[-e^x]_{0}^y=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You forgot a minus sign in e-power in last line: $\int_0^y\frac12e^{-x}dx=\frac12[-e^{-x}]^y_0=\frac12(1-e^{-y})$

Comment: Sure, I was wrong to transcribe. I edit!